# TransactionScope issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactionscope

I have in DB the mapped table with id 7, field Taex with value "qwe"

in this code:

```
var fooObj = Foo.GetById(7);
fooObj.Taex = "abc";
using (new TransactionScope(OnDispose.Rollback))
{
    var originalFooObj = Foo.GetById(7);
    // how can i do to get real original object from database into a transaction
    bool areEquals = fooObj.Taex == originalFooObj.Taex; // are equals
    // because nhibernate gets the cached object.
}
```

i need the db original data into the transaction, how can i do ?

Comment: i tried to use the ActiveRecordMediator.Evict(fooObj) but don't works, i tryed to clone the object but, the lazyed objects (other entities) as properties pass by reference, i will clone them so, some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate has `Refresh` method. You can use it to force NH to reload entity from DB

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have it already:

```
var fooObj = Foo.GetById(7);
var tempTaex = fooObj.Taex; //**get the original value
fooObj.Taex = "abc";
using (new TransactionScope(OnDispose.Rollback))
{
    var originalFooObj = Foo.GetById(7);
    // how can i do to get real original object from database into a transaction
    bool areEquals = fooObj.Taex == tempTaex; //**use it
    // because nhibernate gets the cached object.
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but the scope is to get the original data from the db, this is only an example, inmy real world application it's more complex.